# Compact transfer of partially empty blockdevice images for further compression

Tags: linux, backup, sparsefile

I like to do backups from a bunch of linux block devices on remote machines. Currently I am transferring the complete block device, albeit almost empty, to the backup machine and compress or deduplicate it afterwards (Multiple methods are in use for that).

Now I encounter images to large for the backup machine and transfering GBs of zeros is not useful either.

Compressing the whole data isn't useful either, as it would prevent deduplication and useful incremental indexing at the backup compression process.

So how can I compact the block device data, preferably without installing further tools despite standard linux / GNU utilities, without compressing the non-zero data?

Comment: If deduplication will be done _after_ the transfer, why does it hurt if the data is temporarily compressed _during_ the transfer?

Comment: Because data needs also to be compacted (eg. zero blocks removed) for storage, because the backup machine can't store the almost-empty image file as a whole.

Comment: Actually one would say, why having empty space and use large devices? But as of today, smallest SSDs available in large quantities aren't small. So vanilla installations usually result in large volumes almost empty.

Comment: I would have expected the empty blocks to deduplicate particularly well.